# I need an adjective to precede the word "method"

Tags: adjectives

I am writing a scientific article and I need to give an adjective to a method that I am describing. The method introduces fuzzy logic, which could be the basis for the adjective.

Comment: What you are asking for is not very clear.

Comment: "Stochastic", perhaps?  (Your description is not very precise.)

Comment: You are going to have to address the context concerns expressed in the comments or this question will be closed soon. The best approach might be to write your phrase using words you don't like and ask for smeone to propose something better. I suppose better, to you, would be as a one word adjective.

Answer (score 2):

Did your have a look at Google Books?

Certainly

["fuzzy-logic method?"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22How%20many%20stops%20until%3F%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22fuzzy-logic%20method%3F%22)
About 3,250 results

works.

Similarly,

"fuzzy method"

is accepted too:

> Fuzzy Logic with Engineering Applications - Page 504 Timothy J. Ross -
>   2004
>
> ... and then use a fuzzy chart that is somewhat similar to the
>   standard p-chart technique [Parkinson, 2001 ]. In both case studies,
>   **the fuzzy method** proved slightly superior

and out there.

Comment: A fuzzy logic method is per-se a method, which is probably what is described in the book you have pointed out. What I really want is a way to quality a method that uses fuzzy logic (method) to solve a problem.

Comment: @JRL I am sure that both "fuzzy logic method" or "fuzzy method" are used for what you mean. Have a look at the papers resulting from my search and see the exact context in each of them.

Comment: @JRL If you want  a more detailed name, you need to tell us what your method exactly does.

Comment: I would need more information about the method to describe it. Otherwise try "fuzzifying"

Comment: The pragmatic approach method?  The fuzzy logic approach?  Fuzzy-esque?  Please, we're all on tenterhooks to see a more complete description of the method -- a whole sentence or two.  Otherwise we're just grasping at straws.

Answer (score 1):

Since fuzzy logic is based on approximations and probabilities, you could say *approximate method* or *probabilistic method*.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a method that **produces** or **depends on** *fuzzy logic* it could be called a *[distorted](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/distorted)* *method*. From the Oxford Dictionary Online:

> 2 Giving a misleading or false account or impression; misrepresented:

Comment: Fuzzy logic doesn't give a distorted or false result. It just uses methods that are based on probabilities rather than precise values.

Comment: It seems like you're confusing fuzzy logic with fuzzy thinking. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic